# Modify selected object values in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like this :

```
let arr = [{
  x: 2,
  y: 2,
  z: 2,
  w: 2,
  name: 'John Doe',
  occupation: 'student'
}]
```

Every object in the array has about 30 fields. And I have some fields that are of type Number, that I want to modify, something like this:

```
arr.forEach(data => {
  data.x += 5
  data.y += 5
  data.z += 5
  data.w += 5
  
  return data
})
```

This works, but I have about 10 params (the number might increase in the future) in the object that I will add 5 to, and I don't like the look of it. I was wondering if there is a shorter way of doing this?
And, I want to return the whole object, not just the params that I modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.forEach(data => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof data[key] === "number") {
            data[key] += 5;
        }
    })
    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes an array of properties that you want to change and value that you want to add and the use `map` and `reduce` methods to return new array of objects.

```js
let arr = [{
  x: 2,
  y: 2,
  z: 2,
  w: 2,
  name: 'John Doe',
  occupation: 'student'
}]

const add = (arr, props, value) =>
  arr.map(o => props.reduce((r, e) => {
    r[e] += value
    return r;
  }, { ...o }))


const result = add(arr, ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'], 5)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you, I'd advise not to mix keys-to-mutate with keys-to-persist in one object:

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "John Doe",
  occupation: "student",
  coords: {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    z: 2,
    w: 2,
  },
}];
```

… and then simply:

```js
for (const item of arr) {
  for (const coord in item.coords) {
    item.coords[coord] += 5;
  }
}
```

… or:

```js
arr.forEach((item) => {
  Object.keys(item.coords).forEach((coord) => {
    item.coords[coord] += 5;
  });
});
```

---

If that's not possible (for example, if you don't define items' shapes), you'll have to have an additional list of keys of properties that you want to change:

```js
const keys = [ "x", "y", "z", "w" ];

for (const item of arr) {
  for (const key of keys) {
    item[key] += 5;
  }
}
```

… or vice versa, the list of keys not to mutate (much less performant solution):

```js
const keys = [ "name", "occupation" ];

for (const item of arr) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (!keys.include(key)) {
      item[key] += 5;
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind though, that this approach is not completely [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by writing a generic `map` function -

```js
const map = (o, f) =>
  Array.isArray(o)
    ? o.map(f)
    : Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, f(v)]))

const data =
  { x: 2, y: 2, z: 2, w: 2, name: 'John Doe', occupation: 'student' }

const result =
  map(data, v => Number(v) === v ? v + 5 : v)
    
console.log(result)
```

Output -

```
{
  "x": 7,
  "y": 7,
  "z": 7,
  "w": 7,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "occupation": "student"
}
```